# Upload file button in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, model, backend, upload

I created a **import order button** in sale tab in magento 1 like this in `Model/Observer`:

[image]

```
public function addButton($observer) {
        $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('sales_order_edit');
        if (!$block){
            return $this;
        }
        $order = Mage::registry('current_order');
        $block->addButton('export order', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Export order'),
                'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getButtonUrl($order->getId()) . '\')',
                'class'     => 'go'
        ));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the URL for button click
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getButtonUrl($id)
    {
        return Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/button/expButton/order_id/'.$id, array(
            //'_current'   => false,
            //'back'       => 'edit',
            '_secure' => true
        ));
    }
}
```

Now this button goes to a controller.
How can i make this button to be a "upload file" button, and let me choose a file and upload this file in magento?

I already found this article [Add custom button to upload a file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25653/add-custom-button-to-upload-a-file)
but it not help me to much.

Does anyone know how it's the right way to do this? or can anyone give ma an advice?

Comment: That url gives exact idea what should be done but thats for a form. But my guess is you dont have a form here. To browse files/select files you need to add a button and input type should `file`. Then you can select the file but after that you need to show somepopup or change the button to some other button. Say "import file". Clicking on that button it will upload that file to server.